# Odoo-RMl reports how to use condition

Tags: odoo-8, rml

```xml
<blockTable colWidths="34.0,134.0,50.0,50.0,71.0,100.0,100.0" repeatRows="1" style="Table11B">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <para style="P5">2</para>
        </td>
    </tr>
</blockTable>
```

I want execute the above code only if `object.rentmaterial` is not empty.

Comment: Have you tried anything and can share code with us or just want the full job done for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your condition like this

```
          <para style="P2">
            [[ x.fieldname== True]]
             [[ x.date ]]
          </para>
```